# Creating a relationship in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Being new to phpMyAdmin, I want to create a relation between a column (`column_1`) of one of my tables (`Table_1`) with a column (`column_2`) in another table (`Table_2`).

I first index `column_1` in `Table_1` and when I want to create the relation in relation view tab of `Table_1`, in front of `column_1`, I first choose the database from the first drop down menu, choose the `Table_1` in second drop down menu, but the third drop down menu (Which seems should include `column_2`) has no select options.

My phpMyAdmin version is: 4.1.6.

Below is the result of my "CREATE SHOW my_table":

Table_1:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table_1` (

`column_1` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`column_1`),
KEY `FK_COLUMN1` (`column_1`))
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Table_2:

```
 CREATE TABLE `Table_2` (
`column_2` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`column_2`),
KEY `FK1_COLUMN2` (`column_2`))
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Does that column (column_2) have an index? Only columns with indexes are shown.

Comment: Yes, it already is indexed as well.

Comment: Would you do a SQL dump of the table definitions, and edit it into your question? That will let people try this out in their own PMA installation, and might also indicate instantly what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with PMA. Following query should create the reference. If that fails the error-message will exlpain more ;)

```
ALTER TABLE `this_table`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `name_of_the_constraint` FOREIGN KEY (`this_column`) 
    REFERENCES `external_table` (`external_column`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

`ON DELETE CASCADE` does mean that if the row in `external_table` got deleted, the row in `this_table` also will be removed. Also valid options are `RESTRICT` and `SET NULL`. Same applies for `UPDATE` (row in `this_table` will also be updated).

**Edit:**

To answer your comments: I've run following SQL on a new empty database/scheme and all runs perfectly fine without errors. If it doesn't at your machine I don't know what went wrong (I can't reproduce it). If following also runs at yours, what's different whith that what you were trying before?

```
CREATE TABLE `Table_1` (

`column_1` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`column_1`),
KEY `FK_COLUMN1` (`column_1`))
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `Table_2` (
`column_2` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`column_2`),
KEY `FK1_COLUMN2` (`column_2`))
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `Table_1` (`column_1`) VALUES ( '1' ), ( '2' ); /* Add some both valid as invalid relations */
INSERT INTO `Table_2` (`column_2`) VALUES ( '1' ), ( '3' ); /* Add some both valid as invalid relations */

SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
ALTER TABLE Table_1 ADD FOREIGN KEY (column_1) REFERENCES Table_2(column_2) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
ALTER TABLE Table_2 ADD FOREIGN KEY (column_2) REFERENCES Table_1(column_1) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

NB. Normally you only create the foreign key one direction. I've added both to show that either direction should work in this setup.

Comment: It's worth noting that the default expectation for constraints is `RESTRICT` - most of the time a programmer would want an error on constraint violation.

Comment: I receive the error "#1215 (Cannot add foreign key constraint) which doesn't explain the error well and I couldn't solve this even after several searches, I appreciate if you have any suggestion?

Comment: Can you modify your question and add the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE this_table` and `external_table`? Most likely both columns aren't the exact same type (for example one is `INT(9)` the other `INT(11)`, or one is `UNSIGNED` the other isn't).

Comment: Could it be from the config.inc in which the configuration $cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'],,
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'],
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] appear with error in homepage of phpMyAdmin although I've set them to ' ' value? As for your comment, both are varchar(with the same length)and both are not set to any attribute value(e,g UNSIGNED).

Comment: I`ve created the tables with those queries and mysql runs `ALTER TABLE Table_1 ADD  FOREIGN KEY (column_1) REFERENCES Table_2(column_2) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;` just fine. If you have any data in one of those tables, then it may be that one of the rows has an invalid value (not existing in the other table). You should fix that, or run `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` before your query (use the statement-window in pma, and run both queries in one submit) to ignore it.

Comment: If you're getting errors from your config.inc.php then you should fix that, a lot of things is loaded via json. If json gets mixed with php-errors the browser will not be able to read the json.

Comment: Now after adding SETTING foreign key check to 0, the error changed to #1822 - Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'name_of_the_constraints' in the referenced table 'Table_1'. Not clear to me. Any suggestion?

Comment: My reply was to long to fit in a comment, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify:

Table_1 has an index column1
Table_2 has a column2 that you want to use as a foreign key into Table_1

I think you need to make column1 a Primary Key for Table_1 in order for this to work.

Once you do that, the third drop-down in relationship view for Table_2 will have column_1 as a value that you can select.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer user3901789 , but I re-checked that column_1 is already a primary key for Table_1 and the problem again persists and the drop down menu for column2 relation view has no values. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

select your database

from the menu choose `Designer`

you will find all of your tables .

from the small menu select `create relation` [image]

then choose your `reference key` and your `foreign key`

Comment: Thanks for your solution Hossam Aldeen Ahmed, But When I do it, I receive the error"Relation not added" after clicking OK.